# How to store data in kivy from screen to screen?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to code an app that receives like 30 textinput from the user in a screen, then i wanted to store that data, manipulate with some numpy and plot results on a second screen.
Is it possible to **collect a large amount of textinputs into a variable?** **How can i save all those inputs and manipulate into a plot?**

Comment: This question is basically "how do I make a Kivy app" - all the individual components are standard things to do. Is there a particular aspect you're having trouble with? Have you worked through some Kivy tutorials?

Comment: post your code for us to have a look and we'll be more than happy to assist you